# simple code sql

Tags: sql

can any body tell me why this code doesn't work, I get all employeegrade as 0

```
select Fname,lname, salary, salary =( 
   case when salary>0 and salary <5000 then 1
   when SALARY>5000 and salary <7000 then 2 
   else 3 end )
employeegrade from employee;
```

Comment: Make an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: Why `salary =` at the beginning of `case` expression and `employeegrade` after `case`?

Comment: @Ullas: `employeegrade` is the alias for the expression, I think.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : I think that alias is not required because he is already given `salary =`

Comment: @Ullas: but then he also has a _field_ `salary`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SQL server,you will get the following error while executing the given query.
 " incorrect syntax near 'employee grade'."
The reason is that you are trying to assign the calculated result to two different column names ie. salary and employee grade.

If you wanted to calculate the employee grade, you can use with the below query.

```
   select Fname,lname, salary, employeegrade =( 
         case when salary>0 and salary <5000 then 1
         when SALARY>5000 and salary <7000 then 2 
          else 3 end )
    from employee;
```

OR

```
  select Fname,lname, salary,  
         case when salary>0 and salary <5000 then 1
         when SALARY>5000 and salary <7000 then 2 
          else 3 end  as employeegrade
    from employee;
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
 select Fname,lname, salary, 
(case when salary>0 and salary <5000 then 1 when salary >5000 and salary <7000   then 2 else 3  end) as employeegrade from employee;
```

Comment: You have to explain what is different from the OP query.

Comment: @samsam thanks for reply but still i didn't get point for this answer . i dont know the reason . do you know anything about this

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `salary =` this is interpreted as comparison operator,  so the 0 as false is the result.

Comment: it works thank you Ullas and JYoThI

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select Fname,lname, salary, 
case when salary > 0 and salary < 5000 then 1
when SALARY > 5000 and salary < 7000 then 2 
else 3 end as employeegrade
from employee;
```

Comment: Error with your `case` expression. Check it properly before posting

Comment: can you please notify me where it is ? @Ullas

Comment: No need `salary` after `CASE`. Because anyway you are using a condition with `salary`.

Comment: okay thank you so much @Ullas